# Duplicate a Row in a Dataset and change a value

Tags: java, apache-spark

### My problem

In my Java app I need to parse a `DataSet<Row>`, then duplicate some of the rows according to a function and change the value of one column in the duplicated rows.

Edit : The rows may be duplicated 2 or 3 times according to the map function and each duplicate will have a different value.

### What I have tried

Let's take `DataSet<Row> foo` (the content has been initialised with a parquet file). Now I would like to apply `foo.flatMap(bar, ??)` where `bar` is a `FlatMapFunction<Row, Row>` that return an iterator and `??` is a field that I didn't manage to understand since the documentation is very poor in informations on this method.

The iterator is constructed like this :

```
final List<Row> list = new ArrayList<Row>();
list.add(row);

final Object[] newRow = new Object[row.length()];

for (int i = 0; i<row.length();i++){
    newRow[i] = row.get(i);
}

newRow[row.fieldIndex("fieldName")] = someLong;
list.add(RowFactory.create(newRow));

return list.iterator();
```

### My questions

Am I doing the right way with how I am creating the Iterator ?

What is this mysterious Encoder and what should I put in this field ?

Answer (score 1):

The `flatMap()` documentation says

> Returns a new Dataset by first applying a function to all elements of this Dataset, and then flattening the results.

I think you should instead use `filter()` to get a Dataset, that contains only the rows you want to copy and modify. After that modify those rows using `foreach()` and then `union()` the two datasets.

Please note, that I haven't tried this, so I'm not sure if `filter()` method creates a dataset with new rows or simply references to the rows in the original dataset. If it doesn't create new rows, then simply comply all the filtered rows into a new dataset.

Comment: Thanks ! That should do the trick. I will try it and if it work I will accept your answer.

Comment: In fact this solution won't work easily because I need to be able to duplicate some row more than on time and I don't think this will work with `filter()`